# Storing low-voltage power?

Tags: low-voltage

I'm doing a project for my school which requires harvesting body heat to generate electricity. Now, I've tackled this problem by using TEG, on the chest. Now, the problem is that this TEG is estimated to output as little as 14 mV. This is an extremely low number, and I can't think of a solution to be able to store this power. Is a capacitor gonna do the job?

Comment: Voltage isn't stored, current isn't stored. Power is stored. What current are you looking at? That can be combined with voltage to give you power.

Comment: [this](http://www.ti.com/product/BQ25504) will get you down to 130mV. Google for energy harvesting, your search fu might be better than mine

Comment: @Puffafish energy can be stored but not power. Power is the rate of usage of energy. Voltage can be stored across a capacitor and current can be stored in an inductor (as most clearly seen in a [superconductor causing a frog to levitate](https://www.ru.nl/hfml/research/levitation/diamagnetic-levitation/)).

Comment: A capacitor can store even tiny voltages efficiently, but to do something useful with this energy, the voltage needs to be high enough for the first stage of an electronic converter to function. Since you only have a small temperature difference, you will need to put multiple elements in series until you have a useful voltage.

Comment: And for a TEC or TEG, the larger the temperature differential, the more voltage is generated. So cool the other (non-body) side and the volts will increase.  This of course, will pull more heat from the body.

Comment: The trick is to connect many small generators in series rather than use a single larger one.  For a worn item, this may improve flexibility too.

Comment: Neil, will that boost my voltage to 140mV? But won't that decrease the current?

Comment: And also, cooling the other side will increase voltage? Like a fan on the side exposed to air would do the job? Do you have any suggestions?